# LVM why are new Logical Volumes inactive on boot?

Tags: arch-linux, lvm

I have two separate drives. one is for booting and one is for storage. I created a new logical volume called "lv_storage" in the volume group "ultrabay".

However, when I boot /dev/ultrabay/lv_storage is labeled inactive and therefore cannot be mounted by fstab. So I have to run "vgchange -ay" each time I boot and manually mount the drive.

How can I make LVM activate /dev/ultrabay/lv_storage on boot?

Comment: Is there an uncommented "volume_list" entry in your `lvm.conf` file (usually `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf`)?

Comment: No, the volume_list line is commented. The device is encrypted but is decrypted on boot by dmcrypt after the LVM hook. Could this be the source of the issue?

Comment: what does /etc/sysconfig/lvm or /etc/lvm/*conf (depending on distribution)  say ?  you can check vgs/lvs for details about you current config about this particular LV & dmesg to try to find a warning or error message that explain origin of the issue

Answer (score 2):

You mention in a comment that the underlying device is only decrypted after LVM is set up at boot time. This is the problem. Because the PV is encrypted, the LVM startup can't find it to activate the VG on it. You need to change the order of the decryption / LVM activation, or add a decryption routine to the LVM activation for that PV, or add a `vgchange` to the decryrption routine.